# How to center an object generated by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to HTML5, and I am trying to write a webpage with a jmol image.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JSmol.lite.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Info;;(
    function()
    {
    Info =
    {
    width: 500,
    height: 500,
    debug: false,
    color: "0xC0C0C0",
    addSelectionOptions: true,
    serverURL: "",
    use: "HTML5",
    readyFunction: null,
    defaultModel: ":serotonine",
    bondWidth: 4,
    zoomScaling: 1.5,
    pinchScaling: 2.0,
    mouseDragFactor: 0.5,
    touchDragFactor: 0.15,
    multipleBondSpacing: 4,
    spinRateX: 0.2,
    spinRateY: 0.5,
    spinFPS: 20,
    spin:false,
    }
    }
    )();
</script>
```

I am adding this code into the `<head>` of the HTML, and then adding the following code where I need to insert the image of the molecule.

```html
<script id="java">
   Jmol.getTMApplet("jmol", Info)
</script>
```

However, no matter what I try, I cannot get the jmol picture to the center of the page. I have tried using a class or id in the `<script>` tags, and then adding `display: block;` and `text-align: center;` in CSS. I have also tried `margin: auto;`. But nothing seems to work, the jmol image keeps at the left end of the webpage.

Using the inspect element on the jmol image gives:

```html
<div id="jmol_appletinfotablediv" style="width:500px;height:500px;position:relative;font-size:14px;text-align:left">
<div id="jmol_appletdiv" style="z-index: 9000; width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: block;">
<canvas style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" width="500" height="500" id="jmol_canvas2d"></canvas></div>
<div id="jmol_2dappletdiv" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;display:none"></div>
<div id="jmol_infotablediv" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;">
<div id="jmol_infoheaderdiv" style="height: 20px; width: 100%; background: yellow none repeat scroll 0% 0%; display: none;">
<span id="jmol_infoheaderspan">Jmol._Canvas2D (TwirlyMol) "jmol"</span>
<span id="jmol_infocheckboxspan" style="position:absolute;text-align:right;right:1px;">
<a href="javascript:Jmol.showInfo(jmol,false)">[x]</a>
</span></div>
<div id="jmol_infodiv" style="position:absolute;top:20px;bottom:0px;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:auto"></div></div></div>
```

I am using the lightweight jmol, if you didn't already notice. I am a chemist, and I don't have much experience with coding, so a simple solution would be better.

Comment: The styles you tried to apply, were you applying them to the element with id "java"?

Comment: When [JSmol](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jsmol/) adds an image to the page, you can definitely manipulate it; however, you have not posted that element here. Right-click on the image produced by JSMol, and choose *Inspect element*. That will show you the HTML code used to generate the image. Please add that to your question. Thanks!

Comment: @AnisR., Yes, I was.

Comment: @jpaugh, Added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Script tags in HTML are not rendered on the page, they just execute whatever javascript is inside them. Therefore, applying styles to the `<script>` element won't do anything.

You need to figure out where (i.e. in which div or element) the `Jmol.getTMApplet("jmol", Info)` renders the molecule.

**How to know:**

In your browser, right click on the molecule and select "Inspect element". You will then know in which div/element the molecule is rendered.

Once you find the right element, add to this element the id of "java" for example.

**Edit: ** Just noticed you edited your question, so the element we want to manipulate is the one with ID `"jmol_appletinfotablediv"`

Then using CSS, applying `margin:auto` and/or `text-align:center` to the span element with the correct ID.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to center the element:

- horizontally and vertically:

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
#jmol_appletinfotablediv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

In your case it's not clear who the parent of the #jmol_appletinfotablediv div tag. See where is nested and replace .parent with the actual parent

- Center horizontally

```css
#jmol_appletinfotablediv {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

- Vertically

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
}
#jmol_appletinfotablediv{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Same case with center horizontally and vertically, replace .parent with the actual parent.

- If neither of this works for you, most probably the generated HTML has inlined CSS which overwrites your CSS rules. I haven't tried JMol before, if this doesn;t help you, I'll take another look.

Cheers